# What is required to back up gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci

Since there is no rake task for a gitlab-ci backup, what does a gitlab-ci backup need to do? I am running Gitlab-ci 5.3 (installed via the gitlab 7.6.1 omnibus install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer came from someone inside the [gitlab chat](https://gitter.im/gitlabhq/gitlabhq):

> just backup the database: gitlab_ci_production